# How to get song metadata in React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I wanted to create a mobile player on react native expo, but ran into a problem. I can't get the song data

I tried to get audio files through expo MediaLibrary, but about the song there is only filename. How can I get the song data (title, artist, album, genre and more)